# Saber el puesto final de una clasificación en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Me gustaría saber como crear una columna nueva que contenga la posición final según el total_puntos y el año de la canción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de la consulta:

```
SELECT v.id_cancion
    ,c.año_edicion
    ,sum(v.puntos) AS total_puntos
FROM votos v
INNER JOIN cancion c ON c.id = v.id_cancion
GROUP BY id_cancion
ORDER BY año_edicion
    ,total_puntos DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre después de crear el campo `orden` en tu tabla:

```
ALTER TABLE cancion ADD orden int;
```

Prueba recurriendo a una variable:

```
SET @n=0;
UPDATE cancion c JOIN (
    SELECT
      v.id_cancion,
      SUM(v.puntos) AS total_puntos,
      @n:=@n+1 orden
    FROM votos v
      INNER JOIN cancion c
        ON c.id = v.id_cancion
    GROUP BY id_cancion
    ORDER BY año_edicion, total_puntos DESC
  ) c1 USING(id_cancion)
  SET c.orden=c1.orden;
```

Recuerda ejecutar estas dos últimas instrucciones dentro de la misma conexión.

Si quieres que el orden empiece de nuevo en 1 para cada edición, tendrás que recurrir a algo más elaborado:

```
SET @edicion=0;
UPDATE cancion c JOIN (
    SELECT
      v.id_cancion,
      SUM(v.puntos) AS total_puntos,
      IF(@edicion!=año_edicion,@n:=0,NULL) v1,
      IF(@edicion!=año_edicion,@aut:=año_edicion,NULL) v2,
      @n:=@n+1 orden
    FROM votos v
      INNER JOIN cancion c
        ON c.id = v.id_cancion
    GROUP BY id_cancion
    ORDER BY año_edicion, total_puntos DESC
  ) c1 USING(id_cancion)
  SET c.orden=c1.orden;
```